# validate form data on frontend and backend also using Jquery and Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, validation

i am trying do validate my form data on frontend and backend also using jquery and php using post method on jquery.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is my form how can i validate it on frontend and also backend without page refresh

Comment: You can validate by coding a solution and then ask here

Comment: _i am trying do validate.._ Where is the code that is trying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("button").on("click", function(){
               let email = $.trim($("#exampleInputEmail1").val());
               let password = $.trim($("#exampleInputPassword1").val());

              if(email === ""){
               alert("Email is required!");
               return false;
              }

             if(password === ""){
               alert("Password is required!");
               return false;
             }

             $.post("login.php",{email : email , password : password}, function(response){
              response = JSON.parse(response);
              if(response.success){
               // redirect to homepage
               }else{
                alert(response.message);
               }
             });
             });
            });
            </script>


    login.php

    <?php 
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    if($email === ""){
     echo json_encode(array("success" => false,"message" => "Email is required!")); 
     exit;
    }

    if($password === ""){
      echo json_encode(array("success" => false,"message" => "Password is required!")); exit;
     }


//check the record in db and send back the response

 ?>
```